Excel looping autosave macro only works once then stops
I applied a looping autosave macro script to a workbook last Tuesday and it worked no problem. I come back in today and the last save was at 1:37 am (this morning). I run the script manually and it doesn't loop. Also when I try to close the workbook Excel will hang up indefinitely. I can't figure out what went wrong. Anybody have any idea? Code below:
Option Explicit

Private dtScheduled As Date

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ScheduleSaving
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime dtScheduled, "ThisWorkbook.DoSave", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Private Sub ScheduleSaving()
    dtScheduled = Now + TimeSerial(0, 5, 0)
    Application.OnTime dtScheduled, "ThisWorkbook.DoSave"
End Sub

Sub DoSave()
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ScheduleSaving
End Sub


If you cancel the On Error Resume Next after ThisWorkbook.Save you might at least see any error generated by the following call to ScheduleSaving

Seems to work fine for me in a new empty workbook
